# Drupal creates incorrect index for translatable nodes

Tags: php, solr, drupal

I'm building a multilingual site where during creating/updating node translation jobs start their work and translate node in 20 languages.
Solr is used as a search engine. I use JSON:API Search API to get response in JSON.

But the problem is:
When I make a blank query I get only 3 nodes instead of 6, but all nodes are available for separated search. Also sorting works incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have applied **Translation filter** (in **filter criteria**) and setted a default language
Remove the check then you should get all the results.
hope this helps

Comment: Yes! After manipulations with translation filter it works. Thank you